# Grep on a joined table MySQL/Linux

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, grep, mysql-error-1049

I can't seem to get grep -v "Africa" on this table without throwing errors, can someone help me with syntax in Ubuntu?

There is an error somewhere, and one of my countries doesn't have a macroregion defined (i.e. Americas, Africa, Asia, Europe), and I can't find it. I need to grep this joined table to see which country only has sub regions.

```
select country, group_concat(region) as regions from regions group by country;
```

(footer of which looks like this)

```
| Ukraine                   | Eastern Europe,Europe
| United Arab Emirates      | Middle East,Persian Gulf,Western Asia
| United Kingdom            | Europe
| United States             | Americas,North America
| Uruguay                   | Americas,South America
| Uzbekistan                | Asia,Central Asia
| Vanuatu                   | Australasia,Melanesia,Oceania
| Venezuela                 | Amazon,Americas,Andes,South America
| Vietnam                   | Asia,East Asia,Indochina
| Virgin Islands            | Americas,Caribbean
| Wallis and Futuna Islands | Australasia,Oceania,Polynesia
| Yemen                     | Middle East,Persian Gulf,Western Asia
| Zambia                    | Africa,Central Africa,East Africa,Southern Africa
| Zimbabwe                  | Africa,Central Africa,East Africa,Southern Africa
```

I use:

> mysql -u root -pPASS "use reports"| mysql -u root -pPASS -e "select country, group_concat(region) as regions from regions group by country;"| grep -v 'Africa'

And I get the error:

> ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'use reports' ERROR 1046 (3D000) at line 1: No database selected

Comment: how are you doing the grep (on a saved text file? on a pipe straight from MySQL? etc) and what sort of errors are you getting?

Comment: mysql -u root -pPASS "use reports"| mysql -u root -pPASS -e "select country, group_concat(region) as regions from regions group by country;"| grep -v 'Africa'
ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'use reports'
ERROR 1046 (3D000) at line 1: No database selected

Comment: ryandward@RDW:~$ mysql -u root -pPass -e "use tutorial;select country, group_concat(region) as regions from regions group by country;"| grep -v "Europe" | grep -v "Asia" | grep -v "Africa" | grep -v "Americas" | grep -v "Australasia"
country regions

Argentina   Andes
Philippines South China Sea

This was a horrible thing to figure out, hah, but it worked!

Comment: ah, you got it. :-)  well done.

Comment: @Ryan, please answer your own question and put the solution **not** in a comment, but in the answer. After some time (24 hours IIRC) you can then accept that answer. This way others how have a simular problem can see your question, see that it's been answered succesfully and learn from your mistakes^H^H experience.

Comment: Thanks Spudley haha :) Also I can't answer my own question because I am a new user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mysql -u root -pPASS reports -e "select country, group_concat(region) as regions from regions group by country;" | grep -v 'Africa'
```

first things first:  you selected your database wrong.  The database name is a positional parameter; you don't need to do an embedded sql statement.

secondly, you can't use the `mysql` command in a pipeline and have the first command affect the second, since the database connection is closed prior to the second statement being executed; they're entirely different connections.  Use a semicolon inside the statement if you need multiple queries.  An alternative form of the aforementioned command that does so would look like this:

```
mysql -u root -pPASS -e "use reports; select country, group_concat(region) as regions from regions group by country;" | grep -v 'Africa'
```